# Can't correctly send to kafka-docker from network device

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka, bitnami

I'm trying to setup a Kafka / Docker Setup on my host maschine and connect to it from a network device. I'm using bitnami/kafka. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:29092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

When I run my python script on my host maschine ( not within docker ) and mercury being the name of my host it works just fine:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['mercury:29092'])
print("Connected")
producer.send('topic', b'It works!')
print('Theoretically send')
producer.close()
print('Closed')
```

When I try to run the same script from another network device it doesn't work. I don't even get an error. The script also runs just fine, so there is no delay when trying to connect or sending. That only happens when I f.e. use a wrong port or a topic that doesn't exist. Especially the last part let's me believe that the script can connect but doesn't send the message correctly. I'm not sure why that's the case. Is my port setup correct or do I need some extra kafka environment settings?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the configuration of Kafka's advertised listeners.

**TL/DR;** Change `PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092` to `PLAINTEXT_HOST://mercury:29092` in `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and your Kafka cluster should be accessible from other machines.

In more complex networks, it may be desirable to have an internal network and an external network, for example due to different security requirements. Kafka allows to differentiate between those by setting `listeners` and `advertised.listeners`, respectively.
The entries of [advertised.listeners](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#advertised.listeners) should represent the URLs under which the Kafka cluster can be reached from clients outside the cluster. If this is limited to `localhost`, no machine except your host can connect to the cluster.